# Why does not hold the equality,but the inequality?

Tags: analysis

According to my notes:

$$U(f,P)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(t_{k+1}-t_k) \cdot \sup f(t_k,t_{k+1})$$
$$L(f,P)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(t_{k+1}-t_k) \cdot \inf f(t_k,t_{k+1})$$
$$\text{If } m=\inf f([a,b]), M=\sup f([a,b]), \text{ then }:$$
$$m \cdot (b-a) \leq L(f,P) \leq U(f,P) \leq M \cdot (b-a)$$

But,why is it $m \cdot (b-a) \leq L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P) \leq M \cdot (b-a)$..??

What is the difference so that at both cases does not hold the equality ??

Comment: Try an example with $f(x)=x$, $a=0$, $b=1$, and $P = \{0, 1/2, 1\}$. Also, try drawing a picture to see the inequality.

Comment: So,at this case it is like that?
$$ m(b-a)=0 \leq L(f,P)=\frac{1}{4} \leq U(f,P)=\frac{3}{4} \leq M(b-a)=1 $$

Or have I calculated something wrong?

Comment: Your calculated values are correct. You should note that it's important that the inequalities hold, because if your function is Riemann integrable, then as the mesh of $P$ goes to $0$, you need $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ to become equal; however, $m(b-a)$ and $M(b-a)$ stay constant regardless of $P$.

Comment: @Tom I understand...thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain English, with U(f,P) you are taking the supremum of little pieces of the function (say, supremum of f(x) for x from 0 to 1/4, then from 1/4 to 1/2, etc.) and then multiplying by the length of that piece. It's less than (or equal to) M (b-a) because M is the supremum of the entire range. Since the supremum of the little pieces will always be smaller than or equal to the supremum of the whole range, you get the inequality.

Same logic for L(f,P) and m.

Comment: I understand...thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

Since $m \leq \inf f(t_k,t_{k+1})$, and $\sup f(t_k,t_{k+1}) \leq M$ ,$\forall k \geq 1$. So for example: $L(f,P) \geq \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(t_{k+1} - t_k\right)\cdot m = m(t_n - t_0) = m(b - a)$.

Similarly you get the other inequality for $U(f, P)$.

Comment: I understand...thank you very much!!!